# MongoDB Aggregation on nested documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

I am trying to store data for a jobs in a separate collection and want to use aggregation framework to get desired result from reportData field.

Following is the sample document i am trying to store and update as required and later use mongoose aggregation framework.

```
{
    _id:ObjectId("566824667b51cecc1008d2b0"),
    jobID:"38231623-a7c6-45e5-8624-bf46fee7c095",
    reportData:{
    "38231623-a7c6-45e5-8624-bf46fee7c095":{
    ResumeCount:{
        Pending:4,
        Screened:7,
        Rejected:5,
        OnHold:9
    },
    createdOn:"24/01/2017",
    activeFrom:"28/01/2017",
    closedOn:"24/02/2017"
    },
    "572231213123123":{
        interviewStatus:{
        1:{
            RoundType:"HR",
            at:"24/01/2017"
        },
        2:{
            RoundType:"Technical",
            at:"29/01/2017"
        }   
        },
        candidateStatus:{
        1:{
        status:"Pending",
        at:"18/01/2017 23:45:00"            
        },
        2:{
        status:"ScreenSelect",
        at:"19/01/2017"         
        }           
        }
    },
        "572231213123190":{
        interviewStatus:{
        1:{
            RoundType:"Technical",
            at:"15/01/2017"
        },
        2:{
            RoundType:"Technical",
            at:"18/01/2017"
        }   
        },
        candidateStatus:{
        1:{
        status:"Pending",
        at:"18/01/2017"         
        },
        2:{
        status:"ScreenSelect",
        at:"19/01/2017"         
        }           
        }
    }
    }
}
```

From Above how can i assure that i am inserting new objects for candidateStatus and interviewStatus by knowing the correct number(in this case 3) in reportData field.

Comment: Can you elaborate more your question, please?

Comment: I want to know when i want to insert new object in reportData.572231213123123.interviewStatus. How can i know the next number which i have to use as key to insert the Object(Value).